# auth/popup-closed-by-user error 2 seconds after signInWithPopup

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth to authenticate users and do things on their behalf. I had this working before, and am having trouble figuring out what's going on now.

I'm using the example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) almost unchanged:

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export function signIn() {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');

  console.log('before sign in');
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('success!');

      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;

      const user = result.user;
      console.log(token, user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.code);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('click', ()=>signIn());
```

When I click in the page, this is what happens:

1. The authentication popup opens and the 'before sign in' log is triggered
2. Wait for ~2 seconds
3. signInWithPopup throws a `auth/popup-closed-by-user` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to these HTTP headers I configured on my server:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

I added these when I was experimenting with SharedArrayBuffer. Removing them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had this error on iOS Emulator if I tried to put this into the Info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: It was the case for me as well. If you need to keep it disabled, you would need to handle setting APNSToken manually. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling